# Showing the time every second

Tags: java, awt

This is supposed to show the time but when i run the code I get the time that the code is executed. How can i make it to show the current time every second?

```
    private void Timer(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                       
        DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("HH:mm:ss");
        Calendar cali = Calendar.getInstance();
        cali.getTime();
        String time = timeFormat.format(cali.getTimeInMillis()) ;
        System.out.println( timeFormat.format(cali.getTimeInMillis()) );
        jLabel4.setText(time);
    }
```

Comment: Well you could call that code every second...

Comment: You need to create thread which will update JLable after every second

Comment: Where is the loop that makes you think this happens each second?

Comment: @SachinPasalkar - Dont you think thread is an overkill??.. A simple loop could do it...

Comment: take the help of TimerTask and call the run method every second and in the run method show the time.

Comment: Timer is a keyword in Java. You should rename your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the reference from Ankur's code

```
Timer timer = new Timer("Display Timer");

TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Task to be executed every second
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    Calendar cali = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cali.getTime();
                    String time = timeFormat.format(cali.getTimeInMillis());
                    System.out.println(timeFormat.format(cali.getTimeInMillis()));
                    jLabel4.setText(time);

                }
            });
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

// This will invoke the timer every second
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
```

OR 
Use [The Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a thread and constantly using invokeLater to get back onto the Swing thread this is one of the few cases where a Swing Timer is a good idea.

The Swing Timer already calls back on the Event Dispatch Thread so you can just directly update the label from the callback.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Answer (score 1):

use thread

```
new Thread(new Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (true)
        {
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
            int seconds = time / 1000;
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                 public void run()
                 {
                       label.setText("Time Passed: " + seconds);
                 }
            });
            try { Thread.sleep(100); } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: Would work, but is very inefficient due to the constant message swapping between threads and sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
            Timer timer = new Timer("Display Timer");

            TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   // Task to be executed every second

                    DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    Calendar cali = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cali.getTime();
                    String time = timeFormat.format(cali.getTimeInMillis());
                    System.out.println(timeFormat.format(cali.getTimeInMillis()));
                    jLabel4.setText(time);
                }
            };

           // This will invoke the timer every second
            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: With this code there are chances of deadlock. You should handled case with AWT thread

Comment: The timer code is just a wrapper over the logic mentioned in the question. The question is concerned with printing the time every second which is showcased by the use of timer.

Comment: You should provide the code which will not result in another problem